# How to use end of line character in php on command line?

Tags: php, bash, shell, command-line-arguments

I wish to use php to read command line and write them to a file. However, when I run the following, the while loop does not return if a command line is left empty. How should this be modified?

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$file = fopen("/tmp/test", "a");
fwrite($file, "Script successfully ran at ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."\n");

// read from stdin
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$output = "";
while (!feof($fd)) {
    $line = fread($fd, 1024);
    $output .= $line;
}
fclose($fd);

fwrite($file, $output);
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: I would imagine you could send in <key>Ctrl</key> + <key>Z</key>.

Comment: The while loop doesn't end even if you type a bunch of random keys or enter either.

Comment: I tried combinations of \n, \r, . and they don't work

Comment: To type an `EOF` press `Ctrl+D`. If the EOF does not occur on a line by itself you need to type it twice.

Comment: great! I did `Ctrl+D` on a new line and it worked

Answer (score 0):

control-c will cause test.php to exit

use stream_set_blocking(), see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-blocking.php

after you get $fd call stream_set_blocking($fd, 1)

To write you characters entered on stdin to $file you need to do the fwrite inside the while loop, not after feof is reached.